# ALL keyword in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want the empno who is working on at least all the same projects on which empno 101 is working.

I tried following query but failed:

```
SELECT EMPNO
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE PROJECTNO= ALL(SELECT PROJECTNO
                  FROM EMPLOYEE
                  WHERE EMPNO=101);
```

Empno 101 IS working on comp134 and comp90
and empno 103 is also working on both these projects 
but I get answer as `no rows selected` for following table.

```
projectno empno
--------- ------
comp134      101
comp90       101
comp90       103    
comp14       104
comp213      103
comp134      103
comp14       108
comp90       104
```

Comment: Oracle AND MySQL or only 1 of them?

Comment: what you wished result ?

Comment: only 103.

see i added a row in table comp90 104.

the in clause will give my 103 and 104 also.As 104 is working on comp90 but i want those employee working on all project as the emp101 is working i.e. on comp 134 and comp90 . so the output will be 103.

Answer (score 1):

For *Exact* Match:

```
SELECT EMPNO 
FROM EMPLOYEE E1
WHERE EXISTS
(
 SELECT 'x' FROM EMPLOYEE E2
   WHERE E2.EMPNO=101 AND E1.PROJECTNO = E2.PROJECTNO
)
MINUS
SELECT EMPNO
FROM EMPLOYEE E1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 'x' FROM EMPLOYEE E2
 WHERE E2.EMPNO=101 AND E1.PROJECTNO = E2.PROJECTNO)
```

For Atleast *All* of it Also For *Exact* Match

```
SELECT EMPNO
FROM EMPLOYEE  e
JOIN (SELECT PROJECTNO,count(1) OVER () AS ct
      FROM EMPLOYEE
      WHERE EMPNO=101) my_list
ON (e.PROJECTNO = my_list.PROJECTNO AND e.EMPNO <> 101)
GROUP BY EMPNO
HAVING count(*) = MAX(my_list.ct)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 select `projectno` from 
                    ( select `projectno`, count(`empno`) as counts from EMPLOYEE 
                     group by `empno`
                     order by counts desc
                     limit 1)t  ;
```

or even simpler like that

```
 select `projectno` 
 from EMPLOYEE 
 group by `empno`
 order by count(`empno`) desc
 limit 1
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/765238/1)

Comment: In will give me multiple values that i dont want.
emp 101 is working on two projects if any of the employee is working in any of the one projects will be displayed.

I want the employee who is working in all projects of emp101.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a kind of Relational Division:

```
with cte as
 ( select PROJECTNO
   from EMPLOYEE 
   WHERE EMPNO=101
 )
SELECT EMPNO
FROM EMPLOYEE as e
join cte
on e.PROJECTNO = cte.PROJECTNO
group by EMPNO
HAVING count(*) 
    = (select count(*) from cte)
```